# Como usar chave dinâmica em json multidimensional no v-model em vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou com problema para selecionar os options de um select com os dados de **inicio** e **fim** dentro das chaves dinâmicas do seguinte json multidimensional:

```
 rowsels: {"dias":{"seg":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"ter":{"inicio":"09:00","fim":"15:00"},"qua":{"inicio":"10:00","fim":"19:00"},"qui":{"inicio":"15:00","fim":"17:00"},"sex":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"sab":{"inicio":"24horas","fim":"00:00"},"dom":{"inicio":"fechado","fim":"00:00"}},"obs":"N\u00e3o atendemos em finais de semanas e feriados. Entramos em f\u00e9rias em dezembro at\u00e9 fevereiro."};
```

Eu precisava fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
v-model="rowsels.dias.{{ index }}.inicio"
v-model="rowsels.dias.{{ index }}.fim"
```

Ja tentei de várias outras formas e nada deu certo até agora.

Alguém pode me ajudar? ♥

**Segue o código completo do que estou tentando fazer:**

```js
new Vue({
        el: "#horariosvue",
        data: {
           rowsels: {"dias":{"seg":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"ter":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"qua":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"qui":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"sex":{"inicio":"08:00","fim":"18:00"},"sab":{"inicio":"24horas","fim":"00:00"},"dom":{"inicio":"fechado","fim":"00:00"}},"obs":"N\u00e3o atendemos em finais de semanas e feriados. Entramos em f\u00e9rias em dezembro at\u00e9 fevereiro."},
           rows: {"seg":"Segunda","ter":"Ter\u00e7a","qua":"Quarta","qui":"Quinta","sex":"Sexta","sab":"S\u00e1bado","dom":"Domingo"}
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="horariosvue">
 <div class="form-group" v-for="(row, index) in rows">
  <div class="col-md-2">{{ row }}</div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <select v-bind:name="'horario[dias]['+index+'][inicio]'" 
                v-model="rowsels.dias.{{ index }}.inicio">

    <option value="fechado">Fechado</option>
    <option value="24horas">24 horas</option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
   </select>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <select v-bind:name="'horario[dias]['+index+'][fim]'"
             v-model="rowsels.dias.{{ index }}.fim">

    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
   </select> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz a mesma pergunta no SO em inglês e tive a seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53363391/9441092):

> Use `[]` instead of `{{}}`; mustache `({{}})` is used for text
> interpolation, and [it cannot be used inside HTML attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html), for
> which you need to use javascript expressions:
>
> ```
> v-model="rowsels.days[index].start"
> v-model="rowsels.days[index].end"
> ```

Eu ja tinha tentado de uma forma parecida:

```
v-model="rowsels.dias.[index].inicio"
```

Mas o meu erro foi usar o **ponto** antes do colchete (**dias.[index]**).
O correto deve ser: **dias[index]** ficando assim:

```
v-model="rowsels.dias[index].inicio"
v-model="rowsels.dias[index].fim"
```